# How to make this Python script to run subfolders too?

Tags: python

Which part of the codes do I need to change in order to include subfolders?

File handle.py

```
import glob
import os
import sys
from typing import List


def get_filenames(filepath: str, pattern: str) -> List[str]:
    """Returns all filenames that matches the pattern in current folder.

    Args:
        filepath (str): folder path.
        pattern (str): filename pattern.

    Returns:
        List[str]: list of paths.
    """
    filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath, pattern))
    if filenames:
        return filenames
    return sys.exit("Error: no file found, check the documentation for more info.")
```

Main.py

```
import math

import click

import pdf_split_tool.file_handler
import pdf_split_tool.pdf_splitter


def _confirm_split_file(filepath: str, max_size_bytes: int) -> None:
    """Split file if user confirms or is valid.

    Args:
        filepath: PDF path.
        max_size_bytes: max size in bytes.
    """
    splitter = pdf_split_tool.pdf_splitter.PdfSplitter(filepath)
    valid = True
    if not valid:
        click.secho(
            (
                "Warning: {} has more than 200kb per page. "
                "Consider reducing resolution before splitting."
            ).format(filepath),
            fg="yellow",
        )
        if not click.confirm("Do you want to continue?"):
            click.secho("{} skipped.".format(filepath), fg="blue")
            return
    splitter.split_max_size(max_size_bytes)


@click.command()
@click.version_option()
@click.argument("filepath", type=click.Path(exists=True), default=".")
@click.option(
    "-m",
    "--max-size",
    type=float,
    help="Max size in megabytes.",
    default=20,
    show_default=True,
)
def main(filepath: str, max_size: float) -> None:
    """Pdf Split Tool."""
    max_size_bytes = math.floor(max_size * 1024 * 1024)  # convert to bytes
    if filepath.endswith(".pdf"):
        _confirm_split_file(filepath, max_size_bytes)
    else:
        filepaths = pdf_split_tool.file_handler.get_filenames(filepath, "*.pdf")
        for path in filepaths:
            _confirm_split_file(path, max_size_bytes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(prog_name="pdf-split-tool")  # pragma: no cover
```

pdf_splitter.py

```
import os
import sys
import tempfile

import PyPDF4


class PdfSplitter:
    """Pdf Splitter class."""

    def __init__(self, filepath: str) -> None:
        """Constructor."""
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.input_pdf = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(filepath, "rb")
        self.total_pages = self.input_pdf.getNumPages()
        self.size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
        self.avg_size = self.size / self.total_pages
        print(
            "File: {}\nFile size: {}\nTotal pages: {}\nAverage size: {}".format(
                filepath, self.size, self.total_pages, self.avg_size
            )
        )


    def _get_pdf_size(self, pdf_writer: PyPDF4.PdfFileWriter) -> int:
        """Generates temporary PDF.

        Args:
            pdf_writer: pdf writer.

        Returns:
            int: generated file size.
        """
        with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="wb") as fp:
            pdf_writer.write(fp)
            return fp.tell()

    def split_max_size(self, max_size: int) -> int:
        """Creates new files based on max size.

        Args:
            max_size: size in integer megabytes.

        Returns:
            int: number of PDFs created.
        """
        if self.size > max_size:
            avg_step = int(max_size / self.avg_size)

            pdfs_count = 0
            current_page = 0

            while current_page != self.total_pages:
                end_page = current_page + avg_step
                if end_page > self.total_pages:
                    end_page = self.total_pages

                current_size = sys.maxsize

                # while PDF is too big create smaller PDFs
                while current_size > max_size:
                    pdf_writer = PyPDF4.PdfFileWriter()
                    for page in range(current_page, end_page):
                        pdf_writer.addPage(self.input_pdf.getPage(page))
                    current_size = self._get_pdf_size(pdf_writer)
                    self.input_pdf = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(self.filepath, "rb")
                    end_page -= 1

                # write PDF with size max_size
                with open(
                    self.filepath.replace(".pdf", "-{}.pdf".format(pdfs_count)), "wb"
                ) as out:
                    pdf_writer.write(out)

                current_page = end_page + 1
                pdfs_count += 1
            return pdfs_count
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, for each file in filenames, check if it's a folder, if it is, rerun the function on it, using recursivity

To check wether a file is a folder or not you can use

```
os.path.isdir(path)
```

where path is the path to the file

EDIT: Posting the code is better than an image because it can help people showing you the solution without having to rewrite everything

EDIT2:

You could try doing that, tried it myself and it should hopefully do what you want

```
def get_filenames(filepath, pattern, file_list=None):
    if file_list is None:
        file_list = []
    filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath, pattern))
    if filenames:
        for file in filenames:
            file_list.append(file)
            if os.path.isdir(file): # If it's a folder, rerun the function to get every file inside it recursively
                return get_filenames(file, pattern, file_list)
        return file_list
```

Comment: """File handler module."""
import glob
import os
import sys
from typing import List


def get_filenames(filepath: str, pattern: str) -> List[str]:
    """Returns all filenames that matches the pattern in current folder.

    Args:
        filepath (str): folder path.
        pattern (str): filename pattern.

    Returns:
        List[str]: list of paths.
    """
    filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath, pattern))
    if filenames:
        return filenames
    return sys.exit("Error: no file found, check the documentation for more info.")

Comment: Sorry im new here.. not sure how to add the code here.

Comment: You should edit your post, copy and past the code, higlight it and then use the little {} symbol :)

Comment: u see the code? that's the correct place to amend?

Comment: where to input this ? os.path.isdir(path)

Comment: I see the code yes, you should probably copy the function name too so people can do a simply c/p
I edited to show you a solution, hope it works for you

Comment: that's 3 files for the whole script.. where to change it? thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: Well initially you wanted the function you've put an image to also run subfolder, but seeing the usecase you have, it wouldn't work since you're only looking for pattern with ".pdf" essentially ignoring folder

I think you should delete and remake your question more cleanly so everyone can understand

Comment: Where can I make the changes? This script is to split PDF by file size. I want it to include subfolders too, which part of the code to change in order to get that?

Comment: filepaths = pdf_split_tool.file_handler.get_filenames(filepath, "*.pdf")

Your problem is on that line, now telling you how to change it right now would be hardly readable so I think you should recreate a question cleanly

Comment: i edited my question. u see is that better? Thanks.

Comment: hi Sparkling Marcel u able to help? Thanks.